# XE8 iOS Simulator wont open App

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, ios-simulator, delphi-xe8

I'm currently working on an iOS App in Rad Studio XE8. I try to run it on an Mac mini via PAServer, which made me some trouble. 
NowIi get a connection to the Mac Mini and I am able to deploy my app. The simulator starts and shows the FireMonkey splash-screen for a second but then stops the app. When I try to click on the icon it again shows the splashscreen for a second and closes. I tried it with iPhone5, 5s, 6 and iPad.(all 9.3 iOS).
I even tried to start a new app with nothing in it but with the same results. I really don't know what else I could try to get the app run. Maybe someone had the same problem and will be able to help me.

System: **Xe8 with update1_general
        Mac Mini with PAServer 16.0(with added 17.0 data to use the sim)
        XCode 7.3**